# Unit Testing asserts before the function is complete

Tags: angular, rxjs, jasmine, angular-test

I have a unit test that should assert a value when it was flagged true at some point

```
  it('should tick invalidLogin at error on login', () => {
    var checker;
    var targetObj = new Proxy(component, {
      set: (target, key, value) => {
        if (key == 'invalidLogin' && value == true) {checker = true;}
        return true;
      }
    })
    targetObj.onSubmit(); // empty form should cause error
    expect(checker).toBeTruthy();
  });
```

but the problem is the assertion happens **BEFORE** the property gets flagged.
How can I make it so that the assertion is after?

here's the function that flags the property

```
  onSubmit(){
    if (this.loginform.invalid) {
      return;
    }
    this.isSubmitted = true;
    
    const _id = this.f.username.value
    const _pass = this.f.password.value

    this.authService.login(_id, _pass)
      .pipe(first())
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          this.authService.checkAdmin().subscribe(data => {
            if(this.authService.IsCurrentUserAdmin) this.router.navigate(['admin'])
          });
        },
        error => {
          if(error['status']== 400) this.invalidLogin = true;
          console.log(error)
        },
        () => {
          this.isSubmitted = false;
          
        });
        return
    }
```

**UPDATE**
I ditched this method, and instead mocked the onSubmit() method using a Spy, so i can just flag the property without going through the service.

```
  it('should tick invalidLogin at error on login', () => {
    let button = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#form-login')).nativeElement;
    spyOn(component,'onSubmit').and.callFake(() => {
      component.invalidLogin = true;
    })
    button.click();
    fixture.detectChanges();
    let message = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#invalid-text')).nativeElement;
    expect(message).toBeTruthy;
  });
```